# how to format plotly hovertext

Tags: python, plotly

How do I select data of respective X,Y when I plot text?

I tried different ways cant quite get it

```
traces = []
for i in locations:
      df_tmp = df[df['location']==i ]
        trace = go.Scatter(
                    x = df_tmp['x'],
                    y = df_tmp['y'],

                    mode='lines+markers',
                    # text = ['lom: ' + lom, + '<br>' + df_tmp['number'], df_tmp['x'] , df_tmp['y']],

                    # text = [df_tmp['chainage'].astype(str) + df_tmp['x'].astype(str)],

                    # text = "<br>".join([
                    #     f"lom: {df_tmp['lom']}",
                    #     f"X: {df_tmp['x']}",
                    #     f"Y: {df_tmp['y']}",
                    #     f"datecreated: {df_tmp['date_created']}",
                    # ]),        
            
                    # hovertemplate="Date: y: %{}<br>Day: %{x|%A}<br>Temp: %{y:.2f}",
                    hoverinfo='text'
    )

    traces.append(trace)
```

Here is the df(First loop, everything is basically same after this)

```
    x            y       z       locations                      chainage           date_created
651491.303  4767690.072 -71.744  N1-0APL-DD14-CC15-0A1E-_      0.00 2019-06-24 21:46:07.773
651492.941  4767688.925 -71.690  N1-0APL-DD14-CC15-0A1E-_      2.00 2019-06-24 21:46:07.773
651506.869  4767679.172 -71.231  N1-0APL-DD14-CC15-0A1E-_     19.00 2019-06-24 21:46:07.773
651511.373  4767676.018 -71.082  N1-0APL-DD14-CC15-0A1E-_     24.50 2019-06-24 21:46:07.773
651513.011  4767674.872 -71.028  N1-0APL-DD14-CC15-0A1E-_     26.97 2019-06-24 21:46:07.773
```

I want to show x,y's number in hover but its showing only the first value of df column

Comment: "hovertemplate=" is the way to do it. But unless you share more detail I cant really tell why it's not working for you.

Comment: Yeah sorry bro, added to thread

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

I assigned customdata to my df and called the column from hovertemplate like customdata[0] etc.

```
customdata = df,
hovertemplate="""Location: %{customdata[3]}
                <br>Number:%{customdata[4]}
                <br>Date:%{customdata[5]|%Y-%m-%d}
                <br>x: %{x}
                <br>y: %{y}
                <extra></extra>""",
```

Good luck